# what is sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat

Tags: python, regex

I'm having a problem with a seemingly simple Python regular expression.

```
# e.g. If I wanted to find "mark has wonderful kittens, but they're mischievous.."
p = re.compile("*kittens*")
```

This will fail with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

I'm probably missing something quite simple, regular expressions are certainly not in my strengths!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're confusing regular expressions with [globs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29).

You mean:

```
p = re.compile(".*kittens.*")
```

Note that a bare asterisk doesn't mean the same in an RE as it does in a glob expression.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work perfectly. By the way -- are there any guides to learning RE that you (or anyone else!) would recommend? Python documentation is great and all, but seems a little steep.

Answer (score 3):

`*` is a metacharacter, meaning "0 or more of the preceding token", and there is nothing to repeat for the first `*`.

Perhaps you're looking for word boundaries:

```
p = re.compile(r"\bkittens\b")
```

`\b` ensures that only entire words are matched (so this regex would fail on, ahem, `"kittenshit"`)

Comment: this won't get caught on a `re.match`, but will be caught on a `re.findall` or `re.search` (+1).

Comment: If you're hitting kittens, you and I are going to have words, mister, 75k+ karma or not.

Answer (score 0):

Q. What is re.py, sre.py, sre_constants.py?

Ans. https://blog.labix.org/2003/06/16/understanding-pythons-sre-structure

Code:

```
our_regex = '.*pattern.*('
try:
 re.compile(our_regex)
except Exception, e:
 print e, type(e)

unbalanced parenthesis <class 'sre_constants.error'>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an error that is thrown by the re module it seems.

To handle it import the sre_constants module

This is a small example - using a Pandas data frame (which is what I was having an issue with when I was looking at this).

```
import re
import sre_constants

try:
    df=d[d.Ex_Feed.str.contains('*123', regex=True)]
except sre_constants.error as err:
    print("SRE Error")
except Exception as error:
    print("Some other err Err")
    print("{}".format(type(err)))
    junk=1
finally:
    print("It's time for bed said Zeberdee")
```

Hope that helps